# Take a certain amount of data from a txt file

Tags: python, file

For example, I want to take out the former 30% data from a text file using python.

Here are some codes I have tried to generate two new files, but I don't know how to take a certain percentage of data and write them in.

Here is it:

```
import sys

def NewFile(FileName):
        open(FileName,'r')
        print('Creating new text file')
        #A for 70% training data
        AFileName = 'A'+FileName
        #B for 30% testing data
        BFileName = 'B'+FileName

        try:
                afile = open(AFileName,'a')
                bfile = open(BFileName,'a')
                afile.close()
                bfile.close()
        except:
                print('~~~~~~')
                sys.exist(0)
```

Comment: percentae mean if there are 100 lines do you want 30 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something along these lines, where `filename` is the file you're reading from and `proportion` is the percentage you want in the first file:

```
def split_file(filename, tofile, othertofile, proportion):
    content = open(filename).readlines()
    number_of_lines = len(content)

    # Split content.
    first_portion = "\n".join(content[:number_of_lines * proportion])
    second_portion = "\n".join(content[number_of_lines * proportion:])

    # Write to files.
    open(tofile, "w").write(first_portion)
    open(othertofile, "w").write(second_portion)
```

Comment: The lines already have newline characters at the end. The split index should be an `int` for using it in a slice. Files should be closed after you're done with them. There is no guarantee when that will happen otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well!!! I also find need to add int before the calculation :)))

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
import sys

def NewFile(FileName):
    lines = open(FileName, 'r').readlines()
    print('Creating new text file')
    num_lines = len(lines)
    num_lines_a = 0.7 * num_lines
    #A for 70% training data
    AFileName = 'A'+FileName
    #B for 30% testing data
    BFileName = 'B'+FileName

    try:
        afile = open(AFileName,'a')
        bfile = open(BFileName,'a')
        a = 1
        for line in lines:
            if a <= num_lines_a:
                afile.write(line)
                a +=1 
            else:
                bfile.write(line)
        afile.close()
        bfile.close()
    except:
            print('~~~~~~')
            sys.exist(0)
```

Comment: you can use enumerate ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
from itertools import islice


def new_file(old_filename):
    with open(old_filename, 'r') as old_file:
        lines = list(old_file)
    training_file_line_count = int(len(lines) * 0.7)
    lines_iter = iter(lines)
    with open('A' + old_filename, 'w') as training_file:
        training_file.writelines(islice(lines_iter, training_file_line_count))
    with open('B' + old_filename, 'w') as testing_data_file:
        testing_data_file.writelines(lines_iter)
```